# Set images in Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a problem with images in horizontal scrolling, namely I don´t see the images correctly, my code is following `jsfiddle.net/y8gy6oar/`.

I can´t unterstand how to fix it, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: did you googling on your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width for your article tags to the size of the images.

Of course, this only works if you know the size of your images ahead of time, and they are all the same size.

```
div.horizontal .table article {
    width: 569px;
    height: 320px;
    display: table-cell;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

What is happening in your CSS is the articles are set at 200px so the images are cut off.

Comment: perfect! How much is width with 38 images? Do you use a rule/trick or what?

Comment: I fixed up your jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y8gy6oar/1/. Basically, we float all the articles left and with jQuery we calculate what the total width of '.horizontal' should be. Also, this allows us to not have to define a set size for the 'article' tag. This should allow you have as many articles/images as you like inside '.horizontal'. I made some modifications to your html and css as well.